# CSS transform: rotate does not take effect

Tags: css, transform

So I made this site that shows the planets and their moons from a birds eye view. Now, I know Pluto is not a planet, but I included it because it has lots of moons and it is extremely interesting because of this fact: Pluto and its largest moon Charon orbit EACH OTHER around a point well outside the SURFACE of Pluto. So they do this dance where they have the same orbital period, they are always the same distance away from each other, and always on opposite sides of their orbits (so the distance between them is always maximized). Ok, enough science lecture, onto my problem.

Take a look at the site here: http://distantfuturejosh.com/endomoons/ . You will have to press the right arrow a few times to land on Pluto, then once you do, press the "lock" icon (which constrains the scale) and zoom in for a better view of Pluto and Charon NOT in the right configuration. If you click any where on screen they will begin to orbit for your viewing pleasure.

I can throw Pluto to the opposite side of his orbit by doing a little absolute positioning and margining, but the problem with that is the amount of margin necessary will change as the user scales. I could fix that probably with an if statement but I'd rather not write code that checks every time if the planet (dwarf planet) is Pluto or not.

I would like to solve this with a CSS transform. The problem is, when I apply `transform: rotate(180deg);` (with appropriate prefixes) it doesn't take. Inspect element doesn't show that it's being overridden (its not crossed out) but it just doesn't budge. I don't know what's causing it to fail and therefore I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Yep. Well, a sphere (0rbit) with another sphere (planet) absolutely positioned on its border. Rotating an object should rotate it's contents right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to move Pluto to the opposite side of its orbit. I would suggest getting rid of the calculated `margin-top` and `margin-left` and using percentages instead, as it scales better. Try the following after removing the calculated margins:

```
#Pluto {
   margin-top: 100%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* add vendor prefixed ones as well */
}
```

**Update:** below is a working demo of a very simplified version of your site. I'm using `em` for lengths. This way you could zoom in/out by simply changing the `font-size` in JS (or even in your browser). I hear your concern about rounding, I'm not a 100% sure, but I think browsers that round lengths are going to round your `2244.608px` anyway.

**Working example:** http://jsbin.com/aqiMUxI/5

Comment: You understood the question correctly. I will consider your advice about the calculated margins, but to be honest, they scale beautifully because the precise numbers are stored in my javascript (I don't rely on getting the rounded off css margins and making calculations on them). But applying a translation doesn't work either. Its like it just ignores any transform I apply. Other things work like background color, border etc. But transforms don't. They aren't overwritten, they just don't do anything. Pluto and its orbit are dynamically generated divs. Does that matter with transforms?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that they're generated if the CSS is in your CSS file. I have tried the solution above on your website and it worked. Did you add the other vendor prefixed equivalents? What browser are testing this in?

Comment: Really, it worked? I tried it too. I'm using safari. Anyway, I just went with an if statement (which I wanted to avoid) which applies positions Pluto relatively and to the bottom. I am still confounded as to why transforms weren't working for me. I wish I could have used it.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't use any JS. All I did was uncheck the generated margins in Chrome inspector, then added the above CSS (also in inspector). What I think you should do is add the above CSS to your stylesheet and disable the JS that generates the margins.

Comment: I've created a simplified demo with no JS. You can find the styles in my answer at the very bottom of the CSS section in the jsbin above.

Comment: @wetjosh is the example above not what you're looking to achieve? did I miss something?

Comment: It is, but I really wanted to know the answer the WHY transforms weren't taking effect. Since they worked for you in the browser inspector but didn't for me (in Safari, Chrome and Firefox) I'm still left confounded. Ultimately I solved the issue with a "special case" if-statement that applies the css `position: relative; bottom: -100; top: auto;` to Pluto (which I didn't really want to do, but now that its working it will take a great deal of persuasion to make me go back and fix it :) Hopefully anyone else that has a similar problem will find our ideas and your jsbin useful. Thanks myajouri